# My terminal prompt PS1 mixed up

Tags: bash, bashrc, command-line

By the way I'm on a Mac OS X but I'm connected to an Ubuntu Server.

Yesterday I installed a module for node.js(after a hour I deleted it) which asked me to add something to the .bashrc file and now when I log in with my mac terminal over SSH I see this as my connected name:

```
[e]0;u@h: wa][033[01;32m]u@h[033[00m]:[033[01;34m]w[033[00m]$
```

As I know .bashrc is a file which runs commands when I login, so I thought that this is the problem, so I read a little on the web and some guys recommended to get the original file from:

```
/etc/skel/.bashrc
```

so I copied this file over the running one:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Then I rebooted, and nothing happened. Everything works but my screen name is extremely ugly and I need to use the terminal a lot.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first file you should check is ~/.bashrc. "~" means your home directory. So you need to edit your own .bashrc file firstly, not system wide one. If you want to check the system wide one try /etc/bashrc.

In this file you will see a PS1 section. This is what manages the prompt view.

After editing PS1 line for your needs just run this command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

You don't need to reboot the system.

Comment: And is it good if I overwrite `~/.bashrc` with `/etc/skel/.bashrc`? Just because I don't know what are the original configs.

Comment: Actually you don't need to overwrite it, just edit the PS1 section according to your needs. You can find lots of howto about that. But, if you want to overwrite it you can do this of course. When you log in, first your own .bashrc file is being read. If there is not, the system wide one used.

Comment: I can't even enter to the file with `vi -i ~/.bashrc` because it gives me a lots of errors

Comment: Ok I overwritten with `/etc/skel/.bashrc` and now it works, thanks very much for pointing out the right `.bashrc` file! and the `source` command

Comment: I am glad that it worked. Probably your .bashrc file corrupted somehow.